# Is SignalR relevant at 2020?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sockets, signals

Hello Net developer and I am using SignalR  for Server side (socket). And I have interesting question. At Nuget page there is no update Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR since 4/10/2019 date. Is SignalR still usefull or dead? Thanks for attention!

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client

Comment: New development will be in the .NET **Core** areas - the "classic" .NET 4.8 framework is in maintenance mode, don't expect big developments in that field anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SignalR is relevant for now, it supports mobile devices, and many other things. SignalR is the same WebSocket but with many ready stuff. You can use raw WebSocket instead of it, but you will have to do many things to gain what you want. So SignalR is more easy to use. It was in ASP.NET MVC and now they have it for Core, Microsoft now develop SignalR for Core 5. But how long will they suport it I can't say.

You can take a look for Socket.io and others too.